# Same file, same filesize but the memory comparision returns non zero

Tags: c, file-io

```
#define "/local/home/..."

FILE *fp;

short *originalUnPacked;
short *unPacked;

int fileSize;

fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
fseek (fp , 0 , SEEK_END);
fileSize = ftell (fp);
rewind (fp);

originalUnPacked = (short*) malloc (sizeof(char)*fileSize);
unPacked = (short*) malloc (sizeof(char)*fileSize);

fread(unPacked, 1, fileSize, fp);
fread(originalUnPacked, 1, fileSize, fp);    

if( memcmp( unPacked, originalUnPacked, fileSize) == 0) 
{
 print (" unpacked and original unpacked equal ") // Not happens
}
```

My little knowldege of C says that the print statement in the last if block should be printed but it doesnt, any ideas Why ??

Just to add more clarity and show you the complete code i have added a define statement and two fread statement before the if block.

Comment: Where do you load the two files into the memory pointed to by `originalUnPacked` and `unPacked`?

Comment: Always check return values. You don't check if `malloc` succedded neither if `fopen`,`fread`,`fseek` nor `ftell` were successfull. Do that then tell us if its still doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Few points for your consideration:
1. The return type of [`ftell`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ftell/) `long int` so it is better to declare `fileSize` as `long int` ([as sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c)).
2. [It is a better practice in C not to typecast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835193/is-it-a-better-practice-to-typecast-the-pointer-returned-by-malloc). Also you can probably get rid of `sizeof(char)` when using in `malloc`.
3. [`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) advances the file stream thus after the first `fread` call the file stream pointer has advanced by the size of the file as dictated by `fileSize`. Thus the  second `fread` immediately after that will fail to read anything (assuming the first one succeeded). *This is the reason why you are seeing the behavior mentioned in your program*. You need to reset the file stream pointer using `rewind` before the second call to `fread`. Also you can check the return value of `fread` which is the number of bytes successfully read to check how many bytes were actually read successfully. Try something on these lines:

```
size_t bytes_read;
bytes_read = fread(unPacked, 1, fileSize, fp);
/* some check or print of bytes read successfully if needed */
/* Reset fp if fread was successfully to load file in memory pointed by originalUnPacked */
rewind(fp);
bytes_read = fread(originalUnPacked, 1, fileSize, fp);
/* some check or print of bytes read successfully if needed */
/* memcmp etc */
```

4. It may be a good idea to check for the return values of `fopen`, `malloc` etc against failure i.e. `NULL` check in case of `fopen` & `malloc`.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The memory allocated with [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) is not pre-initialized, so its contents are random and thus almost certainly different for the two allocations.

The expected (probabilistically speaking, "certain") result is exactly what happens.

Did you mean to load the file into both of these buffers before testing with `memcmp` but forgot to do so?