# malloc and scanf string

Tags: c, string, malloc, scanf

A simple program below with malloc and scanf with %s to get a string as below, gives me an output I cannot comprehend. While I have 'malloced' only 5 bytes, my input string has exceeded the above size but no segmentation fault. 
Is scanf overiding malloc allocation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char * name;
  int SZSTRING;

    printf("Enter size of name :");  
    scanf("%d", &SZSTRING);
    name = (char*) malloc ((SZSTRING + 1) * sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter name :");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("len of 'name' : %d\n",strlen(name));

  printf("name final: \"%s\"\n",name);
  free(name);

return 0;
}

Output:

OptiPlex-380:~/gsa/compile$ gcc -o try try.c 
OptiPlex-380:~/gsa/compile$ ./try 
Enter size of name :4
Enter name :qwertyui
len of 'name' : 8
name final: "qwertyui"
```

I noticed one more thing here: with

```
    //scanf("%s", name);
```

output shows

```
len of 'name'= 0
```

and 'malloced' locations were actually memset to NULL. But its calloc and not malloc which initialises the allocated bytes to 0 as per man-page???

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, anything can happen. It can even "work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem to "work" but that's just because you got lucky. When I run your code on one compiler it "works" on a different one it crashes because of a heap corruption. Your best bet if you want to use `scanf()` is to allow scanf() to allocate the memory for you:

```
scanf("%ms", &name); // compiled with -std=c99 this will allocate the correct amount
                    // of memory for you. You can use "%as" if you're using -std=c89
```

Also keep in mind that [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) has a return value (which tells you number of input items successfully matched and assigned) and it's important to check that to know if it worked.

While we're at good practices, you [shouldn't typecast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835193/is-it-a-better-practice-to-typecast-the-pointer-returned-by-malloc)

Another alternative, not using `scanf()`, is to use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead:

```
fgets( name, SZSTRING, stdin);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `&name`? I get segfaults when using `name`.

Comment: @mhutter - Indeed it should be must have missed it when I typed up the answer. Kudos on being the first to catch that in 3 years! ;)

Answer (score 2):

No it doesnt. But exceeding an allocated buffer's size does not always lead immediatly to a segmentation fault. Sometimes areas get corrupted and the effect will show later or even never.

Comment: So I understand, I must manually keep track of the size of final string. Maybe a getchar within a loop was a trustable choice?

Comment: @Aad, you could use `fgets()` and specify the maximum number of characters to read.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that such cases will run without segfault. In this case its just that you are using a space that you haven't claimed, corrupting some memory locations which might are owned by "somebody" else.